# Referências Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

De um tempo para cá o Visual Studio Code deu uma atualizada e desde então para cada variável que eu crio aparece esse "**0 references**" em cima, e isso passou a ser algo bem poluente pra minha vista.

Alguém sabe como remover essa opção?

```
public float speed;
public float jumpForce;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;
```

Comment: mas não desative, você vai se acostumar com essa e outras dicas no seu código e vai perceber a vantagem de ter essas informações sempre à vista.

Answer (score 4):

Essa característica é chamada [**CodeLens**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens).

Para desativá-la no **Visual Studio Code** acesse o menu *File* > *Preferences* > *Settings* > `"editor.codeLens": false`

Essa resposta foi copiada daqui:
[How do I show reference count in Visual Studio Code? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490555/8133067)

Você pode também só digitar *codelens* na caixa de *search* do editor de configurações:
[vscode settings - How to disable codelens in VS code? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813319/8133067)

Complementando, no **Visual Studio** o caminho é menu *Options* > *Text Editor* > *All Languages* > *Enable CodeLens*.